# If a function fg is surjective under composition and f is surjective, is g surjective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If a function $fg$ is surjective under composition and $f$ is surjective, is
$g$ surjective?

I think not, since $f$ could be a many to one function and $g$ could send 
elements only once to elements in g's domain which are many to one elements.

However if $fg$ is injective and $f$ is injective it seems to me that $g$ is too?
Is that right? Thanks

Comment: For the last question if $f \circ g$ in injective then $g$ is injective too no matter if $f$ is or not injective.

Answer (score 2):

You are right on both counts. Suppose $g:A\to B$, $f:B\to C$. For the first question, suppose $C$ has only one element and $B$ has more than one element. Let $g$ be the function that takes every element of $A$ to a fixed element of $B$: $g(x) = b_0$ for all $x\in A$. Then $g$ is not surjective, but $f\circ g$ and $f$ both are.

For the second question, let $A$, $B$, $C$ be arbitrary and suppose $g(a_0) = g(a_1)$. Then $f(g(a_0)) = f(g(a_1))$, or $(fg)(a_0) = (fg)(a_1)$. Since $f\circ g$ is injective, $a_0 = a_1$, so that $g$ is injective. Note that you don't actually need the hypothesis that $f$ is injective (for example, $B$ could be some huge set. $g$ injects into $B$, and its image injects into $C$ under $f$, but the rest of $B$ does not).

Answer (score 0):

No. $g$ is not necessarily surjective in the 1st case. Take $$g:A=\{1,2\}\to B=\{1,3\}$$  and $$f:B=\{1,3\}\to C=\{1\}$$ such that $g$ and $f$ are constant functions: $1$

---

2nd: right.